# Issue with stopword removal function

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I've been building a stopword removal function and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The issue is that's it's returning individual characters instead of words:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

def remove_stop_words(list):
  no_stop_list = []
  for sentence in files:
    for word in sentence:
      no_stops = [word for word in sentence if str(word) not in stop_words]
      no_stop_list.append(no_stops)
  return no_stop_list

no_stops = remove_stop_words(processed_text)
print(no_stops)
```

From what I've read, this seems like it should work. I have a list which has tokenized sentences with in it, and within those tokenized sentences are tokenized words. In this function, my goal is to create a new list, loop through the sentences in the list, then loop through the words in the sentences, check that they're not stopwords, and append the new list with the non-stopword tokens. Despite feeling like this is very logical, it's still not working.

For clarification, processed_text is simply a variable that holds text that has been normalized(new line breaks removed, punctuation removed, etc.)

Comment: Not working?   Can you describe a little more?

Comment: Built-in functions should not be used as variable names. Please choose another name for `list`.

Comment: What is `processed_text`? Can you provide a simple demo?

Comment: Assuming `processed_text` is a list containing sentences, you would need to `sentence.split(" ")` to get `word`.

Comment: @Ghoti: the OP said the list is of tokenized sentences. So they're already split.

Comment: You're expecting word output but getting characters, because there's one unwanted extra level of iteration. **You're wrongly iterating twice over `for word in sentence:` but then also inside the list-comprehension `[word for word in sentence...`.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def remove_stop_words(sentence_list):
    no_stops = [word for sentence in sentence_list for word in sentence  if str(word) not in stop_words]
    return no_stops
```

Comment: Assuming that `sentence_list` is a list of "sentences" and each "sentence" is a list of words, `for` loops are not needed. The list comprehension performs all needed iterations.

Comment: You're right, but without a for loop the function doesn't recognize "sentence"

Comment: Is a sentence a list of words? If it is a string, then you need to split it into words e.g. the way it is done on the answer of @Ghoti.

Comment: the sentence is a list of tokenized words.

Comment: I have just realized that I had wrong iteration order in the function. It is fixed now.